# Eigen Space and Eigen Values, do I use associativity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

(b) Suppose that we are given n × n matrices M,N such that MN = NM. Let λ be an eigenvalue of M and let Eλ be the corresponding eigenspace.
(i) Suppose that v ̸= 0 is an element of Eλ. Show that Nv is also an element of Eλ.

Comment: What is $NMv$? (Yes, you need associativity)

Comment: The expression $(Nv)M$ makes no sense.

Comment: Of course, I see the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If $v\ne0\in E_\lambda$ it follows that:
\begin{equation}
MNv=NMv\\MNv=N(Mv)\\MNv=N\lambda v\\M(Nv)=\lambda (Nv)
\end{equation}

so $Nv\in E_\lambda$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!